# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'dict' and 'float'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I keep on getting that `error` message and I'm stumped and don't know how to fix it.

This is what I wrote:

```
job = {'fireman': 42600, 'programmer': 48700, 'clerk': 23000}

salary = float(job * 1.05 ** years_of_service)

return salary
```

For Question:

```
def salary(job, years_of_service):

    '''(str, int) -> float

Return the salary (in dollars) of a person holding job for
years_of_service.

Each year, a person receives a 5% increase in salary over his/her previous
year. The starting salary for various jobs:

    fireman                                     $42 600
    programmer                                  $48 700
    clerk                                       $23 000

years_of_service will be at least 0.

>>> salary('clerk', 2)
25357.5
'''
```

Comment: `salary = float(job[job] * 1.05 ** years_of_service)`

Comment: I get another error message with this:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying to multiply the entire dict. You need to get the starting salary out of the dict. Due something along these lines

```
salaries = {'fireman': 42600, 'programmer': 48700, 'clerk': 23000}

def salary(job, years_of_service):
    return salaries[job] * (1.05 ** years_of_service)
```

Comment: But now I get TypeError: 'function' object is unsubscriptable

Anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: This is because somewhere you have a function called `salaries` which is the same name as your dictionary.